# Django can't get the correct url path to media file

Tags: python, django, url, request, media

I have a problem when I try to show the media files pictures from my database
Django keeps renaming '/media/' to '/dashboard/' in the requests to my media files
here is the model:`

```
class PetPhoto(models.Model):
photo = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='photos/',
    blank=True
)

tagged_pets = models.ManyToManyField(
    Pet,
)

description = models.TextField(
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)

publish_date = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True,
)

likes = models.IntegerField(
    default=0,
)
```

`Here is the view`

```
class CreatePetPhotoView(auth_mixin.LoginRequiredMixin, views.CreateView):
model = PetPhoto
template_name = 'web/photo_create.html'
fields = ('photo', 'description', 'tagged_pets')
success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

`
Here is settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'mediafiles'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Here is the urls.py file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
              path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              path('', include('petstagram.web.urls')),
              path('accounts/', include('petstagram.accounts.urls')),
          ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please show your template, or how you try to access the media files

Comment: make sure you're accessing your media content like this in your templates *`{{PetPhoto.photo.url}}`* or your *`{{myvar.photo.url}}`*

Comment: @AnkitTiwari that's the problem I had thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not a django expert, but shouldn't it be something like this in the settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = f'{BASE_DIR}/mediafiles'
```

or

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/mediafiles'
```

Comment: Actually,
`MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'mediafiles'`
is Valid if pathlib.Path is used, which it is by default within the django 3.1 settings.py

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of something like that. Good to know.